# XCode won't update app icon.

Tags: cordova, xcode4

I am having trouble making XCode update my iPad app icon. I'm building it using Phonegap/Cordova, but the app icon is built / managed through XCode.

I built the app on my device for testing and it came across with the default Cordova icon, I then added in my own icon into the project by placing them into build summary > app icon. In XCode they show as being there but when I build it to the device, the default Cordova icon still shows. Any ideas?

PS. I'm using XCode 4.3.2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you talking about the app launch icon right ? then the naming convention for iPad app launch icon is icon@2x.png . if it still persist then its the exhaustive cache maintained by xCode :)

Comment: i mean the bit under the target > summary > ipad development info > app icons. Is that the right place to be setting them ? Ive named my icons - Icon-72.png & Icon-72@2x.png is that correct ? Is there a way to clear xcodes cache ?

Comment: im sorry its not icon@2x.png for iPad, its for iPhone 4. plz check the answer below.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

IN this [link](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/39991939/Getting%20Started%20with%20PhoneGap%20iOS%20using%20Xcode%204), third image from the top shows you were to change the icon. you see a folder in the left column Resources->icons. open it in the finder and replace the icon what you have for iPad etc. you can also change the splash screen images in the Resources->Splash section.

to empty the cache delete the app from the device and do a clean and build. Even if its still there(it does at times, trust me), restart your xCode.

Comment: Yup. Seems like there are two keys, at least from what I've seen in my projects: make sure there aren't old resources linked in the "Copy Bundle Resources" section of Build Phases in your target, and make sure to go up to the Product menu and pick Clean every once in a while.

Comment: Didn't know how to clear the cache in iOS simulator. This helped - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

replace the icon@2x.png and Default@2x~iphone.png and then it will work fine.
The new iPhones use 114x114 px icon and 640x960 px Default image

Answer (score 0):

top of the list (hit folder icon), targets group, select your target. hit summary, scroll down to the icons, re-point to the files you want to use. build. deploy. enjoy

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this question asked alot on Stackoverflow and noone seems to have answered it properly yet. This is very simple actually.

For instance if you are using phonegap to build an iOS app, all you need to do is:
replace the default images on

```
www/res/icon/ios/icon-36-ldpi.png
www/res/icon/ios/icon-48-mdpi.png
www/res/icon/ios/icon-72-hdpi.png
www/res/icon/ios/icon-96-xhdpi.png
```

with your icons...

Next, before you can run the app you will need replace the icons on Xcode too:
path should be

```
**YOUR-APP-ROOT/platforms/ios/YOUR-APP-NAME/Resources/icons**
```

the magic lays within "icon.png" and "icon@2x.png" however you should replace all of the icons above, and also make sure you have the correct dimensions for each image you are replacing with, otherwise the app will not built successfully.

Now you are able to

> ```
> phonegap build ios
> ```

followed by :

> phonegap run ios

Have fun!