# XCode won't let me set an app icon/launch image

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4

I have an existing XCode project that I'm reorganising after source files in the SVN repo were moved around.

I have suitable PNG files for the icon and launch images but when I select these in the Target->Summary window, it still displays "No image specified". This happens whether I right-click and select a file, or drag-drop from the image from the media library.

No errors are given. It just doesn't update. Looking in my plistfile, I see Default-Icon~ipad.png (the icon image) has been added 4 times which could be the number of times I tried, but fixing that doesn't seem to help.

I could try delving into the project file by hand if I knew where to look.

Comment: Is this xcode 5 or older?

Comment: 4.5 (latest version of 4)

Comment: I had similar problem (alot of launch images) in my project folder. I had to find all of them (not really that hard for launch images (they are called Default.png and Default@2x.png) delete them and when I was sure, there was none in my project, then I drag&dropped one from different place..... So basically it got messed up, because I had too much "same" files in my project

Comment: Doesn't help - I completely removed the references to the files, so they aren't listed in the project at all. When I selected the images they were added to the project file list, and to the media library, but the 'summary' page still didn't display them.

Comment: I guess size of your pictures is okay (57x57 and 114x114), right?

Comment: Also Apple doc says: "The image files used to represent icons and launch images must all reside in the root level of your bundle." https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW15

Comment: yes, XCode copies them to this location when I select them from elsewhere. These are the exact same images that used to work so I know the size, etc, is good.

Comment: Last thing on my mind is proper naming... Please look at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html and try to name icons correctly.. If that doesn't help, I give up :(

Comment: I've answered that same question here http://stackoverflow.com/a/22582030/907742

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have resolved this by reversing the process. Rather than selecting on the summary screen which files I want, I am adding the files to be copied (icons, launch images, etc) in a build phase (making sure my plist matches). XCode is then automagically picking this up and showing them in the summary page.

Doing it this way also means I can store these image files anywhere I want, they don't need to live in my [project root directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19119382/can-you-put-ios-icon-launch-images-in-a-different-directory-to-the-project-roo) anymore.